# java: incrementing id in constructor to display in main

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I am writing a program to simulate a system in a coffee shop where the person who takes the orders of the customers gives each customer a token number and enters into a system the token number of the customer along with the items s/he has ordered. The `recordOrder` function carries out this operation which allows order details to be input, an order is represented by a ticket ID, tID, and an arrayList of strings representing the items in the order.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ques4 {

private static class Order{
    private static int tID=0;
    private int orderId;
    private String itemName;

    public Order(String itemName){
        tID++;
        this.orderId=tID;
        this.itemName=itemName;

    }

    public int getOrderId(){
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int orderId){
        this.orderId=orderId;
    }

    public int gettID() {
        return tID;
    }

    public void settID(int tID) {
        this.tID = tID;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    /*public String toString(){
        return "Token num: "+gettID()+ " Item name: "+getItemName();
    }*/

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Order> listOfItems= new ArrayList<Order>();
    recordOrder(listOfItems);

}

    private static void recordOrder(ArrayList<Order> listOfItems){

        int n, num_Orders;
        String item = null;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of orders.");
        num_Orders= sc.nextInt();

    for(int j=0; j<num_Orders;j++){
       System.out.println("Enter the number of items for token number "+(j+1));
       n=sc.nextInt();
       sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the items: ");

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        item=sc.nextLine();
    }
    listOfItems.add(new Order(item));
    }

 for(Order list: listOfItems){
     System.out.println("Token num: "+list.gettID()+ " Item name: "+list.getItemName());}   
       }
 }
```

In my Order class, I have auto-incremented the token number so that the first order will have a token number of 1, the second order of number 2 and so on. The problem is that the token number is getting incremented up to the number of orders and the number of orders is getting printed out as the token numbers. That is suppose I enter the number of orders, num_Orders, as 3, I am getting an output of
Token num: 3 Item name: cheesecake

Token num: 3 Item name: fries

Token num: 3 Item name: burger

As I have shown in the output above, only the one and the last item which I have entered for a particular order is being printed out.

**EDIT:**

The output I want is that suppose I enter 2 as the number of orders, I will then be prompted to enter the number of items for token number 1 being the first order and the number of items for token number 2 being the second order. I will further be prompted to enter the item names for token number 1 and 2 respectively. Here is what I want to be displayed:

Enter the number of orders.

2

Enter the number of items for token number: 1

2

Enter the items:

fries

cheesecake

Enter the number of items for token number: 2

2

Enter the items:

hamburger

tacos

Token num: 1 Item name: fries cheesecake

Token num: 2 Item name: hamburger tacos

I am new to data structures and I will greatly appreciate any help, advice and suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
public Order(String itemName){
    tID++;
    this.tID=tID;
    this.itemName=itemName;
}
```

From this constructor it looks like you intended to have two members in your `Order` class, one static counter and one instance variable to serve as the identifier, but you used the same static variable for both.

You need two variables :

```
private static int tID=0;
private int ID;
```

Then in the constructor :

```
public Order(String itemName){
    tID++;
    this.ID=tID;
    this.itemName=itemName;
}
```

Of course you have to change the getter and setter too (they should use `ID`, not `tID`).

EDIT :

There seems to be another problem in this code :

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    item=sc.nextLine();
}
listOfItems.add(new Order(item));
```

Based on the description of your problem, you want to add the item to the list inside the loop :

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    item=sc.nextLine();
    listOfItems.add(new Order(item));
}
```

Comment: @Diksha You are still using `list.gettID()` when you print the output. You should be using `list.getOrderId()`. In fact, I'm not sure you even need a getter and setter for the static counter.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to `list.getOrderId()` and it's working fine but why is only the last item that I input is being printed out?

Comment: @Diksha It's not clear why you have nested for loops.Your inner loop takes multiple user inputs and does nothing with them, so only the last input is used after that loop ends.

Comment: the second loop enters the item names for a particular order. Each order will have a token number and the item names that's why I have two `for` loops

Comment: @Diksha see my latest edit, though I'm not entirely sure that's what you wanted.

Comment: No. Here is what is being displayed: Enter the number of orders.
2
Enter the number of items for token number: 1
2
Enter the items: 
fries
cheesecake
Enter the number of items for token number: 2
2
Enter the items: 
hamburger
tacos
Token num: 1 Item name: fries
Token num: 2 Item name: cheesecake
Token num: 3 Item name: hamburger
Token num: 4 Item name: tacos

Comment: The output based on the inputs should instead have been: Token num: 1 Item name: fries cheesecake Token num: 2 hamburger tacos  because the number of orders is 2 so there should be only 2  tokens (and not 6) with its respective order items

Comment: I edited the body of my post to show the output I want. Please check it. Thanks